# "Your request could not be processed" error in IIS application

Tags: asp.net, iis, asmx

An asmx service we're hosting under IIS decided to attach below message at the top of xml response body rendering the xml invalid. The guid is unique in each response.

> Your request could not be processed. Please press the back button on
>   your browser and try again. If the problem persists, please contact
>   technical support. Information below is for technical support:
>        Support Code: 7d6cbea0-9491-4cb0-9ca0-32f0a8b41bc4

I've limited access to the source; it does not appear like this is coming from the application code itself. [Googling](https://www.google.com/search?q=Your+request+could+not+processed.+Please+press+the+back+button+on+your+browser+and+try+again.+If+the+problem+persists%2C+please+contact+technical+support&rlz=1C1SQJL_enUS817US817&oq=Your+request+could+not+processed.+Please+press+the+back+button+on+your+browser+and+try+again.+If+the+problem+persists%2C+please+contact+technical+support&aqs=chrome..69i57.631j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) brings several hits current or cached having exactly the same behavior (variation of "could not processed" or "could not **be** processed" in different cases):

https://www.histiocure.org/jTlSn/about.aspx

https://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:8gRsTgrCarQJ:https://retirement.insperity.com/education.aspx+&cd=4&hl=en&ct=clnk&gl=us

https://www.perfectprovisions.org/index.aspx

Yet, I don't get any hit from technical sites like stackoverflow or MSDN. This is very puzzling; has anyone seen this behavior? Is it IIS doing this? What causes this?

BTW, the issue itself was resolved when AppPool was restarting but I'm worried that this can happen again anytime unless we get to the bottom of this.

Comment: "I've limited access to the source" is not true. ASP.NET based applications can be easily decompiled and analyzed. For such error pages, since they are not from IIS, can only come from that application.

Comment: as lex li suggested it is not possible by iis you need to implement at the application level. in iis you could only set the custom error pages or custom error message when a request fails.